# I need a general command for this box

Tags: tables, macros

[image]

Hello. This image is from a shhet from my university. I am doing it with:

```
\newcommand{\resii}[2]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
Núm. Objetivo & {#1} & {#2} \\ \hline
0=NL; 1=L     &      &      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\resiii}[3]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
Núm. Objetivo & {#1} & {#2} & {#3} \\ \hline
0=NL; 1=L     &      &      &      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\resiv}[4]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Núm. Objetivo & {#1} & {#2} & {#3} & {#4}\\ \hline
0=NL; 1=L     &      &      &      &      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\resviii}[8]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Núm. Objetivo & {#1} & {#2} & {#3} & {#4} & {#5} & {#6} & {#7} & {#8}\\ \hline
0=NL; 1=L     &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
}
```

and use:

```
\resiv{5}{6}{7}{8}
```

The question is: How to do a general command:

```
\boxres{"cab1 cab2 ... cabn"} % or with two args:

\boxres{n}{"cab1 cab2 ... cabn"}
```

that do a box of n boxes:

```
+--------------+----+----+-----+----+
| OBJ. No.     |cab1|cab2| ... |cabn|
+-------+------+----+----+-----+----+
| 0: NL | 1: L |    |    |     |    |
+-------+------+----+----+-----+----+
```

(Sorry for ascii art and my english!!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \boxres } { m }
 {
   \group_begin:
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|*{20}{c|}}
   \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{OBJ. No.} & 
   \seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_seq { & } { & } { & } \\
   \hline
   0: NL & 1: L & 
   \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq - 1 } { & } \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\boxres{cab1 cab2}

\smallskip
\boxres{cab1 cab2 cab3}

\smallskip
\boxres{cab1 cab2 cab3 cab4 cab5}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I wouldn't use the space as a separator.

Comment: This is good... but is for LaTeX3?

Comment: @Arnoldo Bric: My code uses `expl3` but `expl3` has now been incorporated in the LaTeX kernel. In fac and the LaTeX Team recommends its use.